# Heroku deploy seems to work, but the code on the server does not actually update

Tags: heroku

Today I made a change to my rails app, deployed it to Heroku, and everything seemed fine. But then, when I looked at the production website, my changes were not reflected. I ran `heroku releases` (and looked at their web dashboard version of this information) and indeed it shows my code should be there. It's pointing to the git commit that has my changed code in it as the one that was the most recent release.

Here's where it gets crazy: I use `heroku run bash` to get into the filesystem of my actual server, I use `cat` to view the changed file, and the new code isn't there! It's still the old version.

Has anyone seen this before? What else can I do to debug/fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a large issue with Heroku that seems to be happening.

Their site: https://status.heroku.com/ seems to claim its only for Performance-L dynos. But if you search https://twitter.com/search?q=heroku&src=typd, you'll find convos about a lot of people not seeing the newest code deployed and/or having apps fully crashed.

Comment: Yes, thank you! They finally just posted an update https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1376

Comment: Yeah, it was a terrifying 30 minutes or so for me trying to figure out what I did wrong with a very simple deploy!